# Looking for a general split+merge syntax for IO streams

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, signals, stdout

I often want to perform an operation that requires

1. splitting the `stdout` of a pipeline (let's call it `pipeline-before`) into two parallel streams;
2. feeding the resulting stream, as their `stdin`, to two separate pipelines (`pipeline-between-0` and `pipeline-between-1`);
3. merging the two resulting `stdout` streams *in a strict sequence*;
4. feeding the resulting merged stream, as its `stdin` to another pipeline (`pipeline-after`).

In (3), by "in a strict sequence" I mean that all the output coming from, say, `pipeline-between-0` should appear in the merged output stream before any of the output coming from `pipeline-between-1`.

The whole thing could be diagrammed like this:

```
pipeline-before --.--- pipeline-between-0 -.
                   \                        \
                    `- pipeline-between-1 ---`-- pipeline-after
```

An example of such `pipeline-between-0`/`pipeline-between-1` pair could be:

0. `head -n  1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`
1. `tail -n +2 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1`

In English, one would describe this combination as "make the first row all uppercase, and sort the remaining rows by the first column."

**Q:** Is there a general shell syntax to express such an operation?

I am interested in the answer to this question for both `zsh` and `bash`.

---

Here's one syntax that, in general, does *not* work:

```
$ pipeline-before | tee >( pipeline-between-0 ) | pipeline-between-1 | pipeline-after
```

This syntax fails for two reasons:

1. some of the output of `pipeline-between-1` often appears before some of the output of `pipeline-between-0`.
2. the final output is truncated (I suspect that the reason for this is a `SIGPIPE` signal).

I did try the following [maneuver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582385/10618) (which, I confess, I don't understand 100%):

```bsh
{
  pipeline-before |
  { tee >( pipeline-between-0 4>&1 1>&3 ); } |
  pipeline-between-1
} 3>&1 | pipeline-after
```

AFAICT, this syntax seems to solve the first of the problems listed above (i.e. based on a few informal tests, the outputs of `pipeline-between-0` and `pipeline-between-1` show up in the correct sequence).  Unfortunately, though, the final output is still truncated, at least in some cases.

Comment: Related: [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you just need named pipes (FIFOs)?

Following example:

```
 { seq 1 100000 | grep 1$ & seq 1 100000 | grep 2$ ; } > unsorted
```

should return a mixed result of numbers ending in 1 and 2, respectively, in file `unsorted`. We want them sorted (all numbers ending in 1, then all ending in 2) so now create two named pipes, one for each result, and just concatenate them in the desired order.

```
mkfifo stream{1,2}
{ seq 1 100000 | grep 1$ >stream1 & seq 1 100000 | grep 2$ > stream2 ; } &\
cat stream1 stream2 > sorted
```

Check if the files are in the same order:

```
diff -q {un,}sorted
```

(they should differ) and see if the sorted one is sorted as desired:

```
sed 1,10000q sorted | grep 2$
```

(should be no result, while the `unsorted` file should return data)

Named pipes should work the same way for `bash` and `zsh`.

---

*Or in a most generalized expression with pseudo-code:*

1. The input stream (your "pipeline-before") is replicated into an arbitrary number of parallel streams via `tee` and FIFOs `in-i`.
2. Each stream is handled by a different command in parallel and sends its output to stream `out-i` (your "pipeline-between-i").
3. Concatenate output streams in desired order and forward to next command (your "pipeline-after").

---

```
mkfifo {in,out}-{0..n}

pre-cmd | tee in-0 in-1 ... in-n | cat >/dev/null &
cmd-0 <in-0 >out-0 &
cmd-1 <in-0 >out-0 &
....
cmd-i <in-n >out-n &
cat out-0 out-1 ... out-n | after-cmd
```

I used `cat >/dev/null` instead of `cat >in-n` for reasons of generalization, same for the (possibly) redundant `cat` in the end.

Example:

```
mkfifo {in,out}-{0..2}
seq 0 100 | tee in-{0..2} | cat >/dev/null &
grep '33$' <in-0 >out-0 &
awk '$1<2' <in-1 >out-1 &
sed '/^.\{1,2\}$/d' <in-2 >out-2 &
cat out-2 out-0 out-1 | tr '\n' '-'
```

Result: `100-33-0-1-`

Comment: You have a deadlock: Try replacing `seq 0 100` with `seq 0 10000000`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `parallel --tee`? It should deal happily with any size input as long as you have enough free disk space in `/tmp` for the output.

```
(printf "Header1\tHeader2\n"; paste <(seq 20 -1 11) <(seq 10) ) |
  parallel -k --pipe --tee ::: "head -n  1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'" "tail -n +2 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1"
```

Or the same expressed as bash functions:

```
pipeline-before() {
    printf "Header1\tHeader2\n"
    paste <(seq 20 -1 11) <(seq 10)
}
pipeline-between-0() {
    head -n  1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
}
pipeline-between-1() {
    tail -n +2 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1
}
pipeline-after() {
    echo "This is pipeline-after"
    cat
    echo "Done"
}
export -f pipeline-before pipeline-between-0 pipeline-between-1 pipeline-after

pipeline-before |
  parallel -k --pipe --tee ::: pipeline-between-0 pipeline-between-1 |
  pipeline-after
```

If not, could you elaborate with more examples of input, output and what pipeline-* could be?